# Determine the device by which the image is captured

Tags: iphone

I am working on a camera app where I need to determine by which device the image has been taken and according to the resolution of camera of the device I need to set different overlays on the camera view. for example if I capture image using the iphone3,iphone4,ipad2 and ipad3. I know that the resolution of the camera is different in various devices. Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a project that provides [UIDevice extension methods](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension), one of which is to get the specific device being used. It looks a bit out of date, so not sure if it will have the latest hardware, but it may be a good starting point.

To get the device name as a string, you can import the `UIDevice-Hardware` header, and call:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString];
```